# Calculate coordinates of div elements using d3 and d3.tip

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip

I want my tooltip using `d3-tip` to dynamically be placed next to the text I'm writing out with this code:

in the Javascript

```
$(".intro h2").html("Nextbus prediction of " + "<font size=5>" + cutoff + "</font>" + "minutes really means:")
.on('mouseover', tip2.show)
.on('mouseout', tip2.hide);
```

in the HTML...

```
<div class="intro">
    <span class="underline"><h2></h2></span>
</div>
```

I can make the tooltip appear in an absolute place when I define it like this with the `style("left", 300+"px")`

```
 var tip2 = d3.tip()
        .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
        .direction("s")
        .html(function(d) {
            return "this my text for the hover over of the sentence!"
        })
        .style("left", 300+"px")
        .style("top", 150+"px")
```

But when I take out the `style("left", 300+"px")`, the text is placed in the bottom left corner of the graph, no matter how much I try to hack it `offset.`

I want to replace 300 with something that retrieves to coordinates of the `div` that I'm hovering over with the mouse.

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0yfbhtcv/1/ (Nevermind the plot that doesn't appear... that's just lost in translation from my code to jsfiddle and shouldn't be necessary for this problem)

Comment: I think `d3.tip` will only work within SVGs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't use d3.tip, but I think it does what you want with plain ol d3, it makes a div that you can put HTML or text into that pops up where your mouse is:

```
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   // put the tooltip in a separate div
      .attr("class", "tooltip");
```

then

```
d3.selectAll(".your_class")
    .on("mouseover", function (d) {
      div.transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("opacity", 0.9);
     div.html( d.whatever + <somehtml> + "etc")
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px"); })
    .on("mouseout", function (d) {
      div.transition()
        .duration(300)
        .style("opacity", 0)
    });
```